# prove: $f(x_2)-f(x_1)>(x_2-x_1)f'(\frac{x_1+x_2}{2})$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, inequality

Given $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, so that $f'''(x)>0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

Need to show that for all $x_2>x_1$:

$f(x_2)-f(x_1)>(x_2-x_1)f'(\frac{x_1+x_2}{2})$

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: $f'$ is convex function, then by Jensen inequality 
$$\frac{f(x_2)-f(x_1)}{x_2-x_1} = \frac1{x_2-x_1}\int_{x_1}^{x_2} f'(t) dt \geq f'\left(\frac1{x_2-x_1}\int_{x_1}^{x_2} t dt\right) = f'\left(\frac{x_1+x_2}2\right).$$

Comment: I'd guess you mean $f''>0$, not $f'''>0$.

Comment: @bubba: no, it's the third derivative.

Comment: @nguyen0610 - i didn't understand the integral part.

Comment: @MXYMXY - how can you draw something like that? also i don't understand how to use the fact that $f'''(x)>0$

Comment: @dona: It is just Jensen inequality. You can google it.